# How can I invoke function from page when button, created in content script, is clicked?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In the content script, I'm dynamically adding a button. And I want to execute a function that already exists in the page when a button is clicked. I tried to do:

```
<button onClick="test();">Test</button>
```

But when I click on it, I'm getting error `test() is not defined`.
How can I execute this function?

Comment: To clarify: you really mean it exists in the _page_ scripts and not your content script, correct?

Comment: Can you also add how you're creating the button?

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/912069 which was broken in Chrome 71 and fixed in 72. You'll need to assign the click handler inside a [page-level script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: Please add all relevant code, because what you're trying to do should work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kzx92gey/

Comment: that should work fine if test() is defined properly. how did you define test() function?

Comment: Please note: `test()` was not defined by the OP, and jsfiddle cannot demonstrate this behavior. This is specific to interaction between pages and browser extension content scripts.

Comment: `test()` was already accessible from chrome console before the extension. And I'm adding a button to page as text to `innerHtml`. It renders correctly and I can see `onClick` from the console, but when I click on it I'm getting `test() is not defined` error.

Answer (score -3):

As far as i understand your question, these lines would work for you

```
function oldFunc(){
    console.log("Hello");
}
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.onclick = oldFunc;
btn.innerHTML = "Dynamic Button";
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```